# Write a polynomial with three roots

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I'm currently self studying school math for taking courses in computer science and calculus in future. And I stuck with a problem №194 of book 'Algebra' by Gelfand/Shen.

Here it is:
Polynomial $P=x^3+x^2-10x+1$ has exactly 3 roots which is $x_1,x_2,x_3$. Write a polynomial with integer coefficients which has that's roots:

1. $x_1+1,x_2+1,x_3+1$
2. $2x_1,2x_2,2x_3$
3. $\frac{1}{x_1},\frac{1}{x_2},\frac{1}{x_3}$

Context: chapter 36 which is about remainder when a polynomial divided by $x-a$, where $a$ is a root of the polynomial.

---

I don't quite understand how to start with it. I tried to rewrite it like $P(x) = (x-x_1)(x-x_2)(x - x_3)Q$ (where Q is incomplete quotient) but it didn't give me anything :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint for 1.: If $P$ is any function with root at $x_0$, then $Q$ defined by $Q(x) := P(x-1)$ has a root at $x_0+1$.

2. and 3. are similar.

Comment: +1 for you. For #2, I think you have to consider $2^3P(x/2)$ if you are to retain integer coefficients. It's not immediately obvious to me how to deal with #3 since the roots needn't be integers.

Comment: Oh thank you! I'm gonna try it :)

Comment: @MPW In 3. you take $P(1/x)$, which gives you a rational function. Now just take the numerator. :)

Comment: @Klaus : Ah, yes, very nice

Answer (score 1):

Hint for all three problems:

You can use Vieta's formulae to calculate $x_1x_2x_3$, $x_1x_2+x_2x_3+x_3x_1$ and $x_1+x_2+x_3$ (elementary symmetric polynomials). If the roots of the equation $Q(t)=0$ are $t_1$, $t_2$ and $t_3$, then you can evaluate the elementary symmetric polynomials of $t$ w.r.t $x$. From there, retrieving the original polynomial $Q(t)$ is trivial.

It's your turn now.

Comment: Thank you, but in current context I can't use it. Just because authors hasn't introduced such things in book yet ;)